# Spring boot with JMS (ActiveMQ) queue persistence in Mongo DB

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, spring-mongo

How can I configure a Spring boot application to persist the JMS Queue messages in a MongoDB ?

Comment: I believe this has nothing to do with springboot. You need to check activemq documentation on how to do this. Do you mean you want to connect to Acivemq from springboot, read the message and store in mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spring Integration](https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration) in a boot application.

Use a JMS message-driven channel adapter and a MongoDB outbound channel adapter.

Comment: Can you provide an sample ?